crontabs: no such file or directory
When I'm trying to edit/view crontab on a Debian machine, I get the following errors:
crontabs: No such file or directory
crontabs: mkdir: Operation not permitted

I have tried every available solution, changing permissions on cron files, reinstalling cron, etc... But none of them helped.
The problem seems to be around /var/spool/cron/crontabs. I don't have that directory on this machine and I'm unable to create it.
root@hostname:/etc/cron.monthly# sudo chmod 4774 -R /var/spool/cron
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/spool/cron': Operation not permitted
root@hostname:/var/spool# ls -lha /var/spool/cron/crontabs
ls: cannot access '/var/spool/cron/crontabs': No such file or directory

Service is not running:
root@hostname:~# systemctl status cron
× cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-11-06 00:47:13 CET; 1 day 17h ago
   Duration: 4ms
       Docs: man:cron(8)
    Process: 566487 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 566487 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 3ms

Nov 06 00:47:13 marinero-xs01 systemd[1]: cron.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 06 00:47:13 marinero-xs01 systemd[1]: Stopped cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon.
Nov 06 00:47:13 marinero-xs01 systemd[1]: cron.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 06 00:47:13 marinero-xs01 systemd[1]: cron.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 00:47:13 marinero-xs01 systemd[1]: Failed to start cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon.

Reinstall is successful, but no changes after running it:
root@hostname:/var# apt install --reinstall cron
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/73.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 106926 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cron_3.0pl1-162_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cron (3.0pl1-162) over (3.0pl1-162) ...
Setting up cron (3.0pl1-162) ...

ls -la:
root@hostname:~# ls -la /var/spool/cron
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 30  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb  9  2024 ..

Version info:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm


Is this system a container (Docker, LXC, some kind of VPS)?

sudo apt install cron?

This is a VPS. I was not the maintainer from the beginning.
I have tried reinstalling cron with apt install --reinstall cron, same..

please include the commands you tried to run when you encountered the errors. Without context they are worthless.

So, well, show us ls -la /var/spool/cron, at least. And, the reason I've asked you about a container is that the situation where the root can't change owners or permissions is typical for improperly set unprivileged containers. If the files are owned by some ID not mapped to the container ID range, the "inside" root has no power over them. So I am at the point of asking to provide modes of that file from the host perspective. It is fixed by carefully doing things outside the container, or by correctly recreating it, but since you're not a maintainer, you're probably not able to do that...

Thank you for everyone! I have added more context and commands to my original post.

where's /var mounted from? probably run mount | grep var and edit your question to include it. probably the filesystem /var is mounted from is read-only.
